# Remotely connect Visual Studio 2010 on my windows PC to MySQL Server on my Ubuntu server 11.04; both located on my local network

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010, ubuntu

I have visual studio 2010 installed on my windows 7 machine and I'm trying to open a connection to MySQL server on my Ubuntu server 11.04 located on my local network.

> When I try to create a new connection through visual studio, it says "A
>   network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server.  the server was not found or was not
>   accessible.  Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - could not open a connection to SQL Server)"

It's not recognizing the server on the network.

I got MySQL Workbench on my windows 7 pc to connect to it, so I know the pc has permission and my password is correct.

Any help would be much appreciated.. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems your problem is trying to access your MySQLserver using the SQL Server Named Pipes Provider.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  And I am confused where that came from because I didn't name anything 'Pipes Provider'

Comment: Well it clearly says so in the last line of the error message you got. You need to select a suitable provider to connect to MySQL when adding a connection in Visual Studio.

Comment: How did you set up the connection in Visual Studio? You usually have to tell any software that can connect to multiple database types which kind a given server is explicitly, and possibly provide the right driver. Visual Studio would obviously by default only provide a driver for MS SQL Server and use that.

Comment: Ahh that's the problem.  The Data source I'm selecting is 'Microsoft SQL Server.'  Downloaded the .NET/Mono connector and working beautifully.  Thanks Sii!!

Comment: @dave: Post this comment as an answer and accept it. (Yes, you can answer your own questions.)